# How to obtain toos.jar's PAI guide and java source code

Tags: java, documentation, tools.jar

I hava to referenced something of tools.jar which is a part of jdk lib.
and I want to get its help documentation and java source code.
Please tell me how to get it or where to download.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You are familiar with the openjdk project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant get the source or javadocs for the sun/oracle tools.jar, since that code is not released, but you can go look at the openjdk project's tools, located here - http://openjdk.java.net/tools/index.html

it wont be the same thing, but it'll be close.

Comment: although i am not familiar with openjdk,I will have a try.Thank you.